# Declaring a variable with a string parameter javascript

Tags: javascript

From my understanding when you declare a variable the syntax would look like this:

```
var testing = "testing";
```

This is variable declaration. I am confused how this declaration in my function is actually working:

```
function hello(testing){
  testing = "this works?"
  return testing;
}
hello('what');
```

I pass a string argument to hello. In my eyes I am then doing something like this inside of the function:

```
"what" = "this works?"
return "what"
```

In this case the identifier is a string.  Is the identifier (in this case "what") type converted, how is it ignoring that 'what' is a string? Shouldn't this be a syntax error?

Comment: you just changed the value stored in `testing` from one value to another.

Comment: A variable *evaluates* to a value, and reassignment of a variable changes the value it evaluates to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to grasp the difference between a variable and a value.

When you call hello('what'), you are passing the value 'what' into the function. This value gets assigned to the variable 'testing'. 'testing' is a variable, which is a reference to a location in memory that contains the value 'what', not simply 'what'. Therefore, the function is free to assign a new value (i.e. 'this works?') to the variable testing, which will store that value in that same location in memory.

Answer (score 2):

It is as if you wrote this:

```
function hello(var testing)
```

Except the `var` is automatic here and you must not write it.

Everything becomes clearer once you think about it this way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in a function are variables.

```
function hello(testing) {
  testing = "this works?"
```

works for the same reason as

```
var testing;
testing = "this works?"
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstoud, the `testing` is the variable and `"what"` is  the value inside the variable, when you do

```
testing = "this works";
```

you just assign the value `"this works`" to the variable `testing`, not to the value `"what"`